# Create order programmatically in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I want to create order via code in Craft Commerce. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it's important to know what version(s) of Craft and Commerce you're referring to. The code used in this answer applies to Craft 3, with Commerce 2-beta. Code for Craft 2 and Commerce 1 would look different, but the logic is similar.

---

I would start by looking at Commerce's codebase on Github (or in your plugins folder, if it's Craft 2), and more specifically the [OrdersController](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/blob/develop/src/controllers/OrdersController.php), and even more specifically the `actionSaveOrder` and `_setOrderFromPost` methods.

It looks to me like you need to do two things:

#### Get an Order model:

```
// Find an existing order by ID
$order = Commerce::getInstance()->orders->getOrderById($orderId);

// ... Or create a new one
$order = new Order; # Don't forget to place use craft\commerce\elements\Order above your class
```

#### Populate the model (untested)

If you have an order model, you have to populate all the fields that matter. Status, addresses, I think you'd best start on an individual order page in the admin to see what fields are needed.

```
$order->isCompleted = true;
$order->billingAddressId = 4;
$order->gatewayId = 7;
... etc (includes creating and adding line items for your order)
```

#### Save the order and show why it doesn't work magically the first time around ;)

This is where the fun starts, which might depend on your definition of fun.

```
if (!Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($order)) {
    var_dump($order->errors);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am quite new to craft. So if you can share more detail then it will help me.

Like,
- Adding line items
- Assigning payment method
- Assigning address

Comment: It really depends on your use case and needs. I think you need to familiarize yourself with the underlying code (so, take a look at how Commerce does it) before trying anything as potentially complex as programmatically creating orders. This really is all I can provide you with, time wise, without actually building it for you ;)